# multiplying two large numbers in C / C++

Tags: c++, iostream, bignum

I was trying to come up with the solution for that ... two large numbers, `a` and `b` are represented by `char[]` or `char*` and the goal is to multiply them into a third pointer, `char* c`:

```
void multiply( const char* a, const char* b ){
    int len_a = strlen( a );
    int len_b = strlen( b );
    int* c = new int[ len_a + len_b];
    memset( c, 0, sizeof(int) * ( len_a + len_b ));

    for( int i = len_a - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
        for( int j = len_b - 1; j >= 0; j-- ){
            c[ i + j + 1 ] += ( b[ j ] - '0') * ( a[ i ] - '0' );
        }
    }

    for( int i = len_a + len_b; i >= 0; i-- ){
        if( c[ i ] >= 10 ){
            c[ i - 1 ] += c[ i ] / 10;
            c[ i ] %= 10;
        }
    }

    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << c << endl;
    delete[] c;
}
```

I wrote the above function to do this operation for me ... however, when I use the inputs:

```
int main( void ){
    const char* a = "999";
    const char* b =  "99999";
    multiply( a, b );
    // I expect the answer to be 1 and 6
    // profit = 0.92
    return 0;
}
```

I got:

```
999 * 99999 = 0x100100080
```

Why am I getting the memory address and not the actual number?
Thanks!

Comment: `int *c`, when you output that it will output the pointer.  Don't you mean to make `char *c`?

Comment: Oh, lurvely- the old "I like memory leaks, double deletes, and buffer overruns" style of code.

Comment: @BobFincheimer: Yes, I wanted to do it as a `char* c`. Could you give me an idea how could I write it as a char?

Comment: @DeadMG I don't see any of those in his code.

Comment: @DeadMG: it doesn't seem too bad, maybe the buffer overrun because he forgot the null terminator in the allocation.  But it doesn't seem to be memory leak or double delete style...

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using a multi-precision arithmetic library? Is this homework?

Comment: @BobFincheimer, what if someone flips the bits of the exception mask for `cout`? This type of code has no reason to prefer `new[]` to `vector`.

Comment: Lots of criticism of a newbies code style, little attempt to answer his question.

Comment: If he is trying to read it as a char* , i.e. c-style string, there isn't any string terminating '\0' at the end.

Comment: @john, I for one value the criticism given here. Before starting to be active here, my coding style was completely terrible.

Answer (score 3):

Because `c` is an int pointer and the stream operator for cout will print a memory address if passed such a pointer. To get the value you need to dereference the pointers with e.g. `*c`. You'll probably need to write a loop to print the whole "string" of integers.

Comment: but he is using c like a `char *`, look again, I think he means to have c be a `char *`, not a `int *`

Comment: He's using int* because it's where he's accumulating his intermediate multiplication results. If he used char*, it would overflow.

Comment: Was guessing he was using `int` to somehow have room for the result, but maybe you're right. He does say he wants a `char*` result, but his function actually just lets `c` go out of scope and returns `void` so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << a << " * " << b << " = ";
    for( int i = 0; i < len_a + len_b; i++ ){
        cout << c[ i ];
    }

    cout << endl;
```

will yield the desired result ...

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. 
Just a quick reminder: When you create an integer pointer and want to use it as an array, it points to "the first element of the array" therefore when you print it, you see the address of the first element of the array c, which is "0x100100080" in your case.

To print the number (characters) stored in c you need to de-reference the pointer, i.e., print the elements in the array one after another. Or alternatively you can convert your array into a number and print it at once. For the latter, please refer to: [How to convert array of integers into an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599364/how-to-convert-array-of-integers-into-an-integer-in-c).
For printing the characters one by one you could replace

```
std::cout<<c;
```

with the following code:

```
int n=strlen(c);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    std::cout<<c[i];
}
```

This will print the number.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostream` (of which type `std::cout` is) doesn't have any overloaded operators specifically for `int*`, thus it falls back to the `void*` overload which simply outputs the pointer value in an implementation-defined manner.

Furthermore, it wouldn't be possible for an `int*` overload to determine that the pointer points to an array, and further still, how many elements such an array would have.

Comment: how would I do this operation for a `char*` instead?

Answer (score 0):

for(c++14)
we can use boost libarary..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
int main()
{
  mp::cpp_int s1("12368123681263817263863821638126328136218362182");
  mp::cpp_int s2("345897937325785470923092923709887329092470423707534025");
  mp::cpp_int S=s1*s2;
  std::cout << S << '\n';
  }
```