# How to convert array of integers into an integer in C?

Tags: c, arrays

How can I convert an array of 6 integers into a single integer.  Example provided below of what I want to do.

Array: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

Integer:  `123456`

Thank you!

Comment: Do you realize that this will not be possible if the 6 integers in the array are too big?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, if you get that far, you'll find that the leading zero will disappear: in your example, for instance, the integer will be `123456`. This happens for good reason and should not alarm you.

Comment: Yes, assuming they are not too big.

Comment: So you mean an array of **digits**? Let me tell you, how the decimal system works: `Value=digit(n)+10*digit(n-1)+100*digit(n-2)+...+10^n*digit(0)`

Comment: Also, your example has seven integers. Will there be a set size of the array, or will it change?

Comment: Beware arithmetic overflow.

Comment: If I got a cent every time this exact same question is asked...

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
int i, k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    k = 10 * k + a[i];
```

where `n` is the length of the array. This is true, however, when the array is short enough otherwise you would get an `int` overflow.

Comment: `int a[]={1,3,5,234,1,5,3};`  Bounds were not mentioned, but could be a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I made

```
int array_to_num(int arr[],int n){
    char str[6][3];
    int i;
    char number[13] = {'\n'};

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) sprintf(str[i],"%d",arr[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)strcat(number,str[i]);

    i = atoi(number);
    return i;
}
```

where `str[6][3]` means there are `6` elements that can hold `2` digit numbers, change it to suit your needs better. Also `n` is the size of the array you put into the function.
Use it like this:

```
int num[6] = {13,20,6,4,3,55};
int real_num;
real_num = array_to_num(num,6);
```

`real_num` will now be `132064355`

Comment: What about arithmetic overflow?

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 43, 4, 27};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int n = 0;
    int number  = 0;
    int val  = 0;
    while(n <size)
    {
        val = arr[n];
        while(val!= 0)
        {
            val = val/10;
            number = number*10;
        }
        number = number + arr[n];
        n++;
    }
    printf("%d", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int n;
    char buff[100];

    sprintf(buff,"%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", 0, 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    n = atoi(buff);

    printf("the number is %d",n);

}
```

another version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int n;
    int i;
    char buff[100];
    int x[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        sprintf(&buff[i],"%d",x[i]);
    }
    n = atoi(buff);

    printf("the number is %d",n);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the ***[range of integer values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)*** are:  –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
Any list of numbers in an array (such as what you are describing) will need something bigger than an int to hold value for which the number of digits representing that value is greater than 10, and then, the first digit can only be 2 or less, and so on...  (if you want more digits, use `__int64`)

This will return an integer comprised of the elements of an int array...

(note, things like negative values are not accounted for here)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int ConcatInts(int *a, int numInts);
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int m[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int size = sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0]);

    a = ConcatInts(m, size); //a = 123456789

    return 0;   
}

int ConcatInts(int *a, int numInts)
{
    int i=0, size;
    int b=0;
    int mult = 1;
    size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    for(i=0;i<numInts;i++)
    {
        if((a[i] < 0) ||(a[i]>9)) return -1;
        if(i==0)
        {
            b += a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            b *= 10;
            b += a[i];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The special case test `if (i==0)` is not necessary, since b starts out as 0 and so `10*b` is *also* 0. More important: you cannot use `sizeof` on an array pointer. Fortunately, it just adds dead code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert the array values into a string and then cast to an Int when necessary? Of course, being aware of limits, as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = A.length; i > 0; i--){
    k += 10 * i * A[A.length - i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert each item in the int[] to a string, and add the strings together, and then convert that back into an integer

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But it would be better to put this as a comment for the question